# How can I vertically center using \multirow

Tags: tabularx, multirow

I'm trying to vertically center the first two columns, `Learning Object`, `Data Properties`, and `Object Properties`  but it doesn't work.

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{m{2.5cm}|m{2cm}|p{3cm}|p{5cm}}
    \caption{Classes and Properties of EOMPP} \\
    \toprule
    \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Property} & \textbf{Description} \\
    \midrule
    \centering \textit{\textbf{Learning Object}} \multirow{2}{*} & \centering Data Properties \multirow{6}{*}  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar\\
     & & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
     &  & bla bla blae & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
     & \centering Object Properties \multirow{6}* & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
     &  & bla bla bla  &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
     &  & bla bla bla &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
     &  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
     &  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
     &  & bla bla bla &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
```

I get this:[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Comment: in `tabularx` one column minimum has to be `X` type where auto indenting will take place -- I have put it at the last column -- the `multirow` command needs to be put at the beginning and not at the end of the code -- the number of rows in `\multirow{5}{*} {Data Properties}` can be changed for fine tuning

Comment: Note that you can use \raisebox to achieve the same effect as \multirow, although the parameters are a bit tricky.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/265749/multirow-reacting-to-rownumber-instead-of-linenumber/265774?r=SearchResults&s=3|19.3989#265774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `\multirow`  (the number of rows) is valid for one-lined cells. In other cases, you have to count the total number of lines in these rows, and you even can use a number with a decimal part to fine-tune the position of the \multirow contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}X}
   %\caption{Classes and Properties of EOMPP} 
    \toprule
    \textbf{Class} 
        & \textbf{Feature} 
            & \textbf{Property} 
                & \textbf{Description} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{18}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Learning Object}}}  
        &  \multirow{5}{*} {\centering Data Properties}  
            & bla bla bla 
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar\\
    & & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
    &  & bla bla blae & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    \cmidrule{2-4}
    & \multirow{13}{*} {\centering Object Properties} & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    &  & bla bla bla  &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    &  & bla bla bla &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    &  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
    &  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    &  & bla bla bla &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @TheSoldier: Thaanks for the edit! It seems I had a copy-paste accident (the code on my system is indeed \multirow{13}).

Answer (score 3):

With `tabularray`. Compared to other table packages, the tabularray in multi row cells takes into account the number of adjacent rows in instead lines of text in those rows and not number of spanned text lines in them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tblr}{hline{1,Z} = 1pt, hline{2}=0.6pt,
             colspec = {@{} *{2}{X[1,c]} X[1,l] X[2.5,l] @{}},
             column{1} = {font=\bfseries},
             row{1}  = {font=\bfseries},
             }
Class   & Feature 
            & Property 
                & Description                               \\
\SetCell[r=9]{l}    \itshape Learning Object
        & \SetCell[r=3]{c} Data Properties   
            & bla bla bla
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar                   \\
        &   & bla bla bla 
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar   \\
        &   & bla bla blae 
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar   \\
    \midrule
        & \SetCell[r=6]{c} Object Properties 
            & bla bla bla 
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar   \\
        &   & bla bla bla  
                &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
        &   & bla bla bla 
                &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
        &   & bla bla bla 
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
        &   & bla bla bla
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
        &   & bla bla bla
                & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: compared to other table packages, the tabularray in multi row cells takes into account the number of lines in the neighborhood]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow, booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{3cm}X}
%       \caption{Classes and Properties of EOMPP} 
        \toprule
        \textbf{Class} 
            & \textbf{Feature} 
                & \textbf{Property} 
                    & \textbf{Description} \\
        \midrule
        \multirow{18}{*}{\textit{\textbf{Learning Object}}}  
            &  \multirow{5}{*} {Data Properties}  
                & bla bla bla 
                    & foo bar foo bar foo bar\\
        & & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
        &  & bla bla blae & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
        \cmidrule{2-4}
        & \centering Object Properties \multirow{6}* & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
        &  & bla bla bla  &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
        &  & bla bla bla &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
        &  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar  \\
        &  & bla bla bla & foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
        &  & bla bla bla &  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```